# HTML5 video streaming with POST filepath

Tags: php, html, post, get, video-streaming

I'm currently working on HTML5 video streaming.

This is the VideoStream code I use.
https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293

Here's the code with GET, which works great:

iframe.php

```
<?php
$video=$_GET['target'];
$filePath="./video/".$video.".mp4";
//
VideoStream code
//
$stream = new VideoStream($filePath);
$stream->start();
?>
```

index.html

```
<form action="iframe.php" target="my-iframe" method="get">
<label for="text">videoPath</label>
<input type="text" name="target" id="text" value="video">
<input type="submit" value="post">
</form>
<iframe name="my-iframe" ></iframe>
```

However, when I change method="post", and $video=$_POST['target'];

It doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to use method=post for this purpose the way your code is set up. The iFrame is the cause of your issue. I am not sure why but the iFrame cannot accept the POST variable when loaded back into the main page. However the iFrame can remember the GET variable.

If you still want to use post I think you need to figure out a way to remove the iFrame all together and just use one PHP page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure iFrame can accept POST variable. It's easy to tell that iFrame had accept the POST value with some simple if statement.